# How to get the byte[] from a protocol buffer serialized data for writing to database?

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Protocol buffers to store serialized data in Database for a web application built in java.

I have created .proto files and compiled them to get the generated classes. Also I can build the message objects using the setters & finally build() method. But to store it to database, I need serialized data as byte[] or byte buffers. How do I finally get that from the message instances ??

```
    import com.paratha.serializers.protocolbuffers.CommentProto.Comment;

    Comment.Builder comment=Comment.newBuilder();
    comment.setCommentBody("This is the first comment!").setUserId(32433).build();
```

**How do I get the serialized data from here to write to database ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google have made it very easy :) :

```
MyProtocolBufferObject myObject = MyProtocolBufferObject.newBuilder().setName("bob").build();
byte[] bytes = myObject.toByteArray();
```

**Edit**
With your example:

```
Comment.Builder commentBuilder=Comment.newBuilder();
Comment comment = commentBuilder.setCommentBody("This is the first comment!").setUserId(32433).build();
byte[] bytes = comment.toByteArray();
```

Note that when you call the `newBuilder()` method you are getting an instance of `Comment.Builder`, *not* an instance of `Comment`. It is only when you call the `Comment.Builder`'s `build()` method that you get an instance of `Comment`.

Comment: The Builder pattern is a really nice pattern for avoiding creating constructors for every conceivable scenario.  You just need to remember you don't actually get the object you want until the build() method is called :)